# detect banner pop up from any other app

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, notifications

In iOS, is there a listening function that will enable an app detect when there is a banner (from any other application like whatsapp/snapchat/iMessage banners) on the screen/UI?
For example, to detect brightness change I have something like this:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            self,
            selector: #selector(self.levelChanged),
            name: .UIScreenBrightnessDidChange,
            object: nil)
```

I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32074252/receiving-meaningful-notifications-from-other-apps-and-notificationcenter) post, which is similar but I want my app to just know (on a binary level) if there is a banner or not, I do not need to know the content or source app of the banner.

Comment: By "banner pop up" you mean a notification? As the linked post said - you can't know about notifications from other apps.

Comment: What purpose you have. May be it can have a different solution

Comment: I just need my code to react to banner notifications when they appear on the screen from other apps